# GCP Firewall rules

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firewall

Will creating a firewall rule, say for allowing ingress TCP on port 80, deny any other ingress traffic in all other ports, or should we create firewall rules for explicit deny on other ingress protocols and ports in GCP?

Answer (score 2):

Firewall is implicit deny by default. You just need to open the ports that you need.